# Pi4 update fails

Tags: raspbian

I have a problem with a missing pubkey and with some files and the more I try the worse it gets. So here it is the all message.

I'm new on this machine with no knowledge in code.

I'm located in france.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update

Atteint :1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Atteint :2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease              
Atteint :3 http://repository.shadow.tech/prod bullseye InRelease               
Atteint :4 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                
Err :3 http://repository.shadow.tech/prod bullseye InRelease
  The following signatures could not be verified because the 
public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 581A1D4A3BA85044 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree
Reading status information... 
Done  
All packages are up to date. 
N: "shadow-prod.listsudo" in directory 
"/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" was ignored 
because it uses an invalid extension 
W: An error occurred while checking the signature.
The repository is not updated and previous index 
files will be used. 
GPG error: http://repository.shadow.tech/prod bullseye 
InRelease: The following signatures could not be verified 
because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 581A1D4A3BA85044 
W: Unable to retrieve

http://repository.shadow.tech/prod/dists/bullseye/InRelease
The following signatures could not be verified because the 
public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 581A1D4A3BA85044
W: Some index files failed to download, were skipped, 
or used old ones instead.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: I ran your error through **Google Translate**, this works quite well for technical stuff because the grammar etc. is usually proper.

Comment: The file name `shadow-prod.listsudo` is suspicious. Probably you made some mistake during the installation of "shadow". How exactly did you install this? What installation inctructions did you follow? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://help.shadow.tech/hc/en-gb/articles/6387060736668-How-to-install-Shadow-on-Raspberry-Pi) to install Shadow

Comment: and dont mix repositories, you have both bullseye and buster.